# How to close msi db opened by python msilib?

Tags: python

When I edit an `msi` file using `msilib` followed by moving the `msi` file into another directory move command fails because the `msi` file is still opened. I haven't found any method to close msi db opened by `msilib.OpenDatabase(msifile, MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT)`. Can anybody give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

If database is assigned to local variable inside a function, then it will be closed after function return:

```
import msilib

def edit_msi(filepath):
    # global db
    db = msilib.OpenDatabase(filepath, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT)
    # operations on db
    # ...
    # end of edit_msi()

edit_msi(f)
edit_msi(f) # uncomment 'global db' and this will fail
```